# 0-score accepted answer?

Tags: bug, reputation

*Finally catch a day when Jon Skeet scores less than 100! :-) Weird and some more weird.*

Below is a day-view of his reputation change under graph view. Can anyone explain why there is a **`0-score`** shown there? Shouldn't it always be 15 for accepted answer? Clearly it should not be related to day reputation limit here.

P.S. I did check these two answers, and it had never received any down-votes (sure he did, just to clarify though).

[image]

Comment: Are they community wiki by any chance?

Comment: @Mysticial Ahhh, yes. Make sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't get rep for accepting your own answer, or for accepted community wiki answers.

Comment: By accepting your own answer and if it is has a score of 0, does that count towards earning the "Tenacious" or "Unsung Hero" badges?  Just curious.  Personally, I don't think it should, but I don't know how it currently stands.

Comment: @SlyRaskal: No, Tenacious and Unsung Hero only apply to answering questions that are not your own.

Comment: @SlyRaskal: from the [badges faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions): *Community wiki answers, deleted answers, and self-accepted answers are not included in any calculations*

Comment: Thanks for the info @MartijnPieters.